# gtk/gtk.h file not found on Mac

Tags: macos, gtk

In order to learn the gtk library on mac, I wrote a very short code to create a window with the title 'hello world'.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
         GtkWidget *window;
         gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

         window =  gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
         gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Hello World");
         gtk_widget_show(window);

         gtk_main();
         return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile this code using `gcc`, it didn't work, leaving a message that the `gtk/gtk.h` file is not found. I checked out if the gtk library is properly installed, and I found out that the gtk library is located at `/usr/local/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h`.

How should I fix this matter?

Comment: Show the command line you use to compile.

Answer (score 4):

Now I became clear with everything. The reason I kept failing to compile the source code was not because I didn't have the gtk+ library installed, but I put the wrong command on terminal.

I kept the following command to compile, and it did not work at all.
`gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld`

In order to compile a source code that contains the gtk library, the command must be as follows.

`` gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs` ``

Now it is well compiled!!